# How can I ask for Google Drive access from asp.net API

Tags: asp.net-core, google-drive-api

Using ng-gapi (Angular), I'm already able to ask the users for permission to access their Google Drive. But I would like to try something different.

I would like to achieve the same result (open popup asking for permission), but at this time from a ASP.NET Core API. Kind the same way that I already do the login:

```
new ChallengeResult(
GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
new AuthenticationProperties
{
    RedirectUri = Url.Action("...", "...", new { ... })
});
```

But this time, I know that I need to add Scope, discoveryDocs, client_id, etc... I just don't know how.

Comment: This might help you get it working with asp.net core https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/1584

Comment: When you did the `.AddGoogle(options => .... )` you should have some scope on that options because it'a  GoogleOptions. This should be in your `Startup`

Comment: Even adding the scopes, I still not able to get the tokens after the user allow the application `await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)`.

Comment: Hello there @Pablo, what exactly do you mean by "I am not able to get the tokens after the user allows the application"? Can you update the question and add what you have tried in this step as well? Also, what scope/s did you use?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Google.Apis.Auth.AspNetCore3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Auth.AspNetCore3/) for authenticating in .NET Core 3.1, it is the Google maintained and recommended library. The [Google.Apis.Auth.AspNetCore3.IntegrationTests](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/tree/master/Src/Support/Google.Apis.Auth.AspNetCore3.IntegrationTests) is a good example (it's just an ASP.NET Core 3 Web Application) of how to use the library and shows all of its features, including authorization and using incremental scopes.